# Google Chrome Will Install Shortcuts as Programs and will not let me uninstall them

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, controlpanel

I create a windows shortcut using the method of going to the three dots in the top right corner then clicking more tools then clicking create shortcut.
click uninstall program in windows 11 control panel and nothing happens.

I click uninstall in windows 11 settings app manager and nothing happens.

I run the registry editor as an administrator and cannot find a single program (that would share the same name as the shortcut) in the pathway,
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.

I uninstalled chrome and reinstalled it and the shortcuts are still appearing in my programs list in windows 11
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here are some screenshots of the problem:

[Program Uninstall Page not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ac8.png)

I have tried using the registry editor, to no avail. I have installed and uninstalled chrome, to no avail. No matter what i do, it won't uninstall. The first time i tried to uninstall it, it showed a chrome popup saying uninstall. It seemed like it worked and removed from the start directory, but is still remaining in add/remove programs control panel page.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the data stored at following location in Registry Editor.

**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**

Expand the **Uninstall** section and you will see 32-bit named folder.

**Click** on it and look for the **"DisplayName"** to check which shortcut that you would like to delete.

Then **deleted** that particular 32-bit folder and done.